# Why does %%timeit work fine in Jupyter Notebook but throws SyntaxError in Python Shell IDLE?

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, timeit

```
%%timeit
d = deque()
for i in range(40000):
    d.appendleft(i)
```

The above code prints out the time of execution in Jupyter Notebook as: 3.39 ms ± 168 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)
However, when I run this code in Python IDLE Shell, it indicates SyntaxError at % in %%timeit. How is that so?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because `%%` is Jupyter's "cell magic": https://ipython.readthedocs.io/en/stable/interactive/magics.html#cell-magics

It's not native Python syntax.

Answer (score 1):

`%%time` is so-called Jupyter's [magic command](https://ipython.readthedocs.io/en/stable/interactive/magics.html).